# How to loop through the number at each index in byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

I'm coding a program to parse xml to a byte array, and need to check the numeric values at certain indexes within the byte array.

For example if `99` is an integer within the array, it should write an error message to the console, same for `999` and `01`.

What I've tried so far is the using a for each loop, but the if..else conditions are checking the *index number*, not the *integer numbers* associated with each index in the array.

Does anyone know how I can loop through the integer values associated with each index? **(shown in the screen shot below)**

This is what I've tried so far, but the loop seems to be checking the index values , not the integer values associated with the indexes, giving false results:

```
private static byte[] requestBytes;

foreach(char i in requestBytes)
{
    if (i == 99)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending Failure..");
    }
    else if(i == 999)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message Failure..");
    }
    else if (i == 01)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending Success..");
    }

}
```

As you can see in the picture, each index has an associated integer value, which I want to check in a loop.

[image: Byte array contents]

Comment: Why is your loop variable of type `char` instead of `byte`?

Comment: `arr[i]` with a regular `for` loop

Comment: How can 999 possibly be a value in an element of the byte array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < requestBytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    var v = requestBytes[i];
                    if (v == 99)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sending Failure..");
                    }
                    else if(v == 999)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Message Failure..");
                    }
                    else if (v == 01)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sending Success..");
                    }

                }
```

Comment: okay will try that solution instead, there is a small typo above..should be for, not foreach.

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake, I was sleepy.